# When solving flight dynamics equations, should the integration variables be set in one or multiple reference frames?

Tags: aerodynamics, simulation, coordinates

when establishing the differential equations of flight dynamics, I have 2 choices:
1、establish the equations in one coordinate system (e.g. in the earth centered inertial system), then doing the numerical integration in one system and convert parameters to other coordinate systems that I'm concerned.
2、establish the equations in 2 or more coordinate systems simultaneously (e.g. set the position in ECI system and in ECEF system as the integral variables at the same time)

which one is better and why? what's the best practice?

Comment: Consider [edit]ing the question to include a *list of variables* that are being integrated. Usually a mix of frames is required.